# BingAds API Type not found Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, suds, bing-ads-api

Our product uses the bingads api v13 to perform some of the CRUD services: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/get-started-python?view=bingads-13. We had an issue today all of a sudden at `campaign_service.factory.create('ns3:ArrayOfstring')` with error: ": ("Type not found: 'ns3:ArrayOfstring'",)". We are wondering if anyone experiences the same issue and knows the root the cause it.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. Our team is investigating and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @EricUrban If this is confirmed to be a known issue, could you update from the official api status page or forum so that we can communicate with our stakeholders?

Comment: This is fixed in Sandbox, and should be in Production soon. Thanks for your patience!